# New sessionid when reload page but the same sessionid when go to another page and back again (Not Working)

Tags: php, sessionid

I am a totaly newbie in PHP and I have a problem with sessions in PHP. I use Chrome browser. I have two pages.

PAGE 1

```
<?php
session_start();
$session_id = session_id(); ?>

<p>
  Page1 session-id = <?php echo $session_id;?> 
</p>
<p>
  <a href="page2.php?session-id=<?php echo $session_id;?>">To page2</a>
</p>
```

PAGE2

```
<p>
   sessions-id from page1 = <?php echo $_GET['session-id']?>
</p>
```

I can go from Page 1 to page 2 and the sessionid stays the same and if I go back from page 2 to page 1 with the back arrow. Here comes my problem. Every time that i reload the page (with the reload page button on the browser) I will get a new session id so I implemented this new code on page 1

PAGE 1

```
<?php
session_start();
$session_id = session_id();
?>

<p>
  Page1 session-id = <?php echo $session_id;?> 
</p>
<p>
  <a href="page2.php?session-id=<?php echo $session_id;?>">To page2</a>
</p>

<?php
 session_regenerate_id();
?>
```

Now I get a new sessionid everytime that i press the reload page botton (on the browser) so far so good. When I go from page 1 to page 2 the sessionid is the same, but when i go back from page 2 to page 1 again the sessionid on page 1 is change.

Can anyone please give me some advice how I can get a new sessionid everytime I reload the page, but keep the same sessionid when I go from page 1 to page 2 and back again?

Comment: you have to use session_start() on page 2 too, not only on page 1.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Erik. I have tested that but it still not working.

Comment: use session_start(); + $session_id = session_id(); + echo $session_id on page1 and page2, and on page2 remove $session_id in url, it's useless and confusing, or change the var_name.

Comment: and remove regenerate_id, it generate a new session , and it is not your goal, Use it when you want logout.

Comment: Wow now it is working perfect. Thank you very much Eric.